# Ist there a way to define custom language in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting, text-editor

is there a way to define a custom language in Eclipse IDE?

Background: I am developing my own theme for Wordpress. Now I want to highlight the shortcodes which are i. e. `[runningtomy_code_begin lang="php"]` and other custom language parts in my post.

Best regards

Comment: Eclipse [xText](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/)

Comment: For syntax highlighting you can also use [Eclipse tm4e](https://github.com/eclipse/tm4e).